# Postgres: Get percentile of number not necessarily in table column

Tags: postgresql

Imagine I have a column `my_variable` of floats in my a `my_table`. I know how to convert each of the rows in this `my_variable` column into percentiles, but my question is: I have a number `x` that is *not necessarily* in the table. Let's call it `7.67`. How do I efficiently compute where `7.67` falls in that distribution of `my_variable`? I would like to be able to say "7.67 is in the 16.7th percentile" or "7.67 is larger than 16.7% of rows in `my_variable`." Note that 7.67 is not something taken from the column, but I'm inputting it in the SQL query itself.

I was thinking about ordering `my_variable` in ascending order and counting the number of rows that fall below the number I specify and dividing by the total number of rows, but is there a more computationally efficient way of doing this, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```
select (avg(dummy_var::float)) 
from (
  select case when var_name < 3.14 then 1 else 0 end as dummy_var 
  from table_name where var_name is not null
)
```

Where `var_name` was the variable of interest, `table_name` was the table of interest, and `3.14` was the number of interest.

Comment: This solution only works as an approximation. For example, if your table has the following values `[1,2,3,4]`, and your number of interest is 3, the percentile will be 0.5, when it should be 0.75.

Answer (score 1):

If your data does not change too often, you can use a materialized view or a different table, call it `percentiles`, in which you store 100 or 1.000 (depending on the precision you need). This table should have a descending index on the `value` column.

Each row contains the minimum value to reach a certain percentile and the percentile itself.

Then you just need to get the first row that have value greater than the given data and read the percentile value.

In you example the table will contain 1.000 rows, and you could have someting like:

`Percentile   value
   16.9       7.71
   16.8       7.69
   16.7       7.66
   16.6       7.65
   16.5       7.62`

And your query could be something like:

`SELECT TOP 1 Percentile FROM percentiles where 7.67 < value ORDER BY value desc`

This is a valid solution if the number of SELECTs you make is much bigger than the numbers of updates in the `my_table` table.

Comment: Actually, it's nice to consider the possibility of having the value of interest in the Percentile table.  Also, you should use `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`:  `SELECT Percentile FROM percentiles WHERE 7.67 <= value ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1`.